# Checkbox selected index changed function is not called even after checking

Tags: c#, asp.net

On selecting a item, the change event is not triggered.

ASP Page:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="name" DataValueField="name"
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged"> 
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

CS code: (this function is not called after selecting an item)

```
   public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
   {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Chart1.Visible = false;
    }

    protected void CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Chart1.Visible = true;


        CDLDataAccess.dao.Insert("inside");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to put.. **AutoPostBack="true"**

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="true" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="name" DataValueField="name"
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged"> 
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```